# Spark Java: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while broadcasting object of type GenericObjectPool

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kryo

I am working on a spark-streaming project in **java**. I am trying to send some messages from spark to apache **kafka** using kafka-producer java api. Since creating instance of KafkaProducer for each element would be very expensive, I am trying to use a pool of producer using apache common pooling framework. As shown in the code snippet below, I am creating the GenericObjectPool instance and broadcasting it as shown below:-

```
GenericObjectPool<KafkaProducer<String, String>> producerPool = new GenericObjectPool<KafkaProducer<String, String>>(
                new KafkaProducerFactory(prop));
final Broadcast<GenericObjectPool<KafkaProducer<String, String>>> pool = ssc.sparkContext() .broadcast(producerPool);  //**Causing exception**
```

**KafkaProducerFactory class's code is pasted below:-**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObject;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultPooledObject;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;

public class KafkaProducerFactory<K,V> extends BasePooledObjectFactory<KafkaProducer<K, V>> 
implements Serializable{
    private Map<String,Object> configs;
    public KafkaProducerFactory(Map<String, Object> configs) {
        this.configs=configs;
    }

    @Override
    public KafkaProducer<K, V> create() {
        return new KafkaProducer<K, V>(this.configs);
    }

    @Override
    public PooledObject<KafkaProducer<K,V>> wrap(KafkaProducer<K,V> producer) {
        return new DefaultPooledObject<KafkaProducer<K,V>>(producer);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyObject(PooledObject<KafkaProducer<K,V>>obj){
        obj.getObject().close();
    }
}
```

But above line is giving me the below pasted exception:-

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

**Full StackTrace is pasted below:-**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Serialization trace:
classes (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
classloader (java.security.ProtectionDomain)
context (java.security.AccessControlContext)
acc (org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader)
referent (java.lang.ref.WeakReference)
factoryClassLoader (org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:585)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:318)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:549)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:570)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1291)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.broadcast(JavaSparkContext.scala:648)
    at com.veda.txt.spark.Engine.start(Engine.java:63)
    at com.veda.txt.spark.Engine.main(Engine.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.checkForComodification(Vector.java:1127)
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.next(Vector.java:1104)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:74)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:18)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    ... 39 more
15/08/26 20:38:14 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Please suggest me what went wrong.

Thaks

Answer (score 2):

KafkaProducer is not serializable, you can't broadcast it.

In general, for this kind of problem you can use foreachPartition and create your expensive resource once per partition instead of once per element.  If that still doesn't meet your performance needs, you can use a singleton (assuming the object is thread safe, which in the case of a kafka producer it should be).

There's a blog post about this topic that was shared on the spark user mailing list recently:

http://allegro.tech/spark-kafka-integration.html